Use multiple user accounts with own password
I share an Android 14 tablet with another user, each with their own password.
If the other user is active, can I log into my session without having to enter the other user's password?
Is there any way to make it so that, if I want to log in with my user, I just enter MY password to access and not the other user's?
Thanks!
